# SendGrid not send messages with only Bcc addresses

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid, azure-cloud-services

I recently upgraded the SendGrid C# library to the latest version, and I'm unable to send messages with only Bcc addresses.

If I try to add the addresses to the "To" MailAddress[] object, it works and the messages are delivered. If I add the same addresses to the "Bcc" MailAddress[] object, and I don't add anything to the "To" MailAddress[] object, the messages are not processed and delivered.

In both case the DeliverAsync method not return any errors.

Comment: You have to include a TO address, either include sender address itself or some "junk" email address in  `To` that you don't mind getting mail on.

Comment: Yes, if I include a To address it works. So this is a new "feature" of the latest version of c# library?

Comment: "To" has been a required parameter of the mail.send endpoint since SendGrid launched, because it's part of SMTP RFC. Nothing changed on our side.

Comment: Using .NET’s Built-in SMTP Library I'm able to send messages without any "To" address, but only with "Bcc" addresses.

Comment: Email just doesn't work like that. Email messages MUST have To addresses. Across all SMTPs ever.